# How to use multiple middleware in flutter redux app?

Tags: redux, flutter

From the code snippets below, the `AppState` contains 2 lists (`teachers` and `classrooms` lists). The store is assigned to a single middleware `createClassroomMiddleware`, and I want to have another middleware for `createTeacherMiddleware` which is using for CRUD operations on the data. How can I have more than one middleware attached to the store?

I'm currently using `flutter redux` library, and following this [example](https://gitlab.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/tree/master/example/redux)

My appState is

```
         class AppState {
             final List<ClassRoom> classrooms;
             final List<Teacher> teachers; //etc..
             AppState(this.classrooms, this.teachers); 
         }
```

My store:

```
       Store<AppState> {
           initialState: new AppState(const [], const [])
           appReducer,
           middleware: createClassroomMiddleware()
      }
```

My middleware:

```
      List<Middleware<AppState>> createClassroomMiddleware() {
          return combineTypedMiddleware([
             new MiddlewareBinding<AppState, ClassroomLoadedAction>(_loadClassrooms(), 
             new MiddlewareBinding<AppState, ClassroomDeletedAction>(_deleteClassroom()
          ]); 

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution might be easier than you expect!

You can combine these Lists of Middleware together using the `List` class' `addAll` method.

```
Store<AppState> {
  initialState: new AppState(const [], const [])
  appReducer,
  middleware: createClassroomMiddleware()..addAll(createTeacherMiddleware())
}
```

How does this work? Under the hood, the `middleware` parameter allows you to add as many Middleware to your Store as you want, since it's just a `List<Middleware<AppState>>`. Since both of your `createMiddleware` functions return a list, you need to combine those two lists together into one big list.

You do that with the `List` class' `addAll` method, as seen above!

Answer (score 1):

The `middleware` property in the store is a `List<Middleware<State>>`.

If you want to add different middleware in the same store, you need just to concatenate them, and an easy way to concatenate `list` in dart is:

```
[]..addAll(list1)..addAll(list2)..addAll(listn)
```

In your example:

```
class ReduxApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final store = Store<AppState>(
    appReducer,
    initialState: new AppState(const [], const []),
    middleware: []
      ..addAll(createClassroomMiddleware())
      ..addAll(createTeacherMiddleware()),
  );
}
```

Comment: Please, explain your solution rather than just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `createClassroomMiddleware`, name as `createAllMiddleware` and put all middlewares. Will that solve?

Comment: yeah, I have used that approach, but I don't really want to combine all the middlewares into one class, because the there will be a long list of middlewares and it will hard to find later on.

Comment: Can you create two files holding the separate middleware details, e.g.  classroom_middleware.dart and teachers_middleware.dart, then import these into all_middleware.dart where you create your combineTypedMiddleware? The middleware functions cannot be private like in the example repo you mentioned, but seems like it could work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you expected:

```
List<Middleware<AppState>> listMiddleWare = new List<Middleware<AppState>>();

class ReduxApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final store = Store<AppState>(
    appReducer,
    initialState: AppState.loading(),
    middleware: listMiddleWare
      ..addAll(createStoreOne())
      ..addAll(createStoreOrdersMiddleware()),
  );
}
```